# Change of variable in $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}dy$

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

I want to make the change of variable $x=\frac{1}{y}$ in :

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}dy$$

How to do this? The problem I see is that the domain of $y$ is $[-\infty,+\infty]$ but $x$ has domain $[0,0]$

Comment: The substitution $x=\frac{1}{y}$ is not valid as it is not continous at $y=0$

Comment: The function is odd.

Comment: I think you need to assume that the integral is a principal value integral, otherwise this integral does not make sense.

Comment: @mea43 How to deal with such a case? Just to mention this is the expectation of $\frac{1}{y}$ where $y$ is $N(0,1)$. I want to write it as $E(Z)=\int z \phi_Z(z)dz$

Answer (score 2):

Note that the integral is odd, by letting $x=-y$, the integral for $y>0$ is:

$$\int_0^{-\infty} -\frac 1x \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac 12 x^2} (-dx)$$

So it cancels out with the negative part of the original integral

Comment: You mean the whole thing is equal to zero?

Comment: @Daveddd Yes, just like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xdx$, the positive part for $x>0$ cancels with the negative part for $x<0$

Comment: Right. Thank you. How can i write it as $E(Z)=\int z \phi_Z(z)dz$ so the distribution of $\frac{1}{y}$ appears explicitly under the integral?

Comment: @Daveddd Sorry I am not familiar with statistics, so your random variable is $\frac 1y$ ?

Comment: exactly, where $y$ is $N(0,1)$

Comment: @Daveddd Not sure what your question means, isn't your expression simply the expectation?

Comment: it is the expectation, but we cannot distinguish the distribution in my expression

Comment: @Daveddd Sorry what do you mean by distinguish the distribution? From what?

Answer (score 0):

The probability density of the standard normal distribution is
$$\phi\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$$
Also note that the law of the unconscious statistician is
$$E\left[g\left(X\right)\right]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g\left(x\right)\phi\left(x\right)\mathrm dx$$
The integral in question is equivalent to
$$E\left[\frac{1}{X}\right]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\mathrm dx$$
However this integral does not exist because
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\mathrm dx=\mbox{divergent}$$
One could also observe that
$$\mathrm{pv}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\mathrm dx=0$$
However the Cauchy principle value is irrelevant in the context of probability.